# What is the fastest way to total up records in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a faster/better way to accomplish the following in a rails app?  I am trying to get the total of all sales.

```
total = 0
Sale.all.each do |sale|
  total += sale.total
end
puts total
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is the sum method.

```
puts Sale.sum("total")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

ActiveRecord has it's own SQL-like calculations check [API](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000296)

```
Sale.sum('total')
```

should work